# How can I reuse a grails application (Code and Data) by other grails applications?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-plugin, grails-domain-class

I have a grails Application
 http://partner.strotmann.org
https://github.com/pstrotmann/partnerForFree
 managing partner Information like persons, organizations, their resp. adresses, bank data and communication data (email, phone, ..)

As this Application is important for other applications in a company e.g. sales, marketing, human resources etc., it should be reused by those applications with no data redundance and as less code redundance as possible.

My first approach is Rest Webservice, that I implemented for a small production planning system, that just needed the name of the customer.

Is there a more grails like approach ?

Comment: Are you talking about code reuse, or are you talking about integrating a new application with your existing system? - you mention both, and they are pretty different things

Comment: integrating a new application with my existing system. Sorry for the confusion I made by using the term reuse.

Comment: does creating you application as a plugin ,answers your needs?

Comment: I don't think so, because a plugin integrates just the code but not the data

Comment: unless the plugin domainClasses used a new data source that was a shared data source and then  dual datasources in each app with 1 being this shared plugin app set up on all your other apps ? its either that or REST. and REST is a default behaviour now in built in later grails I think 2.4+

Comment: Also http://gr8crm.github.io/ lookup this plug in on youtube. Events used to pass around stuff all based on different  plug in doing independent tasks

Answer (score 0):

For my needs a solution with rest Webservice will do.
First I wrote
https://github.com/pstrotmann/partnerAdapter
that encapsulates rest logic for the applications.
Using that adapter I wrote two simple examples:

http://sale.strotmann.org for English users
http://purchase.strotmann.org for German users

and deployed them on a server residing on a cloud other than partner. You can record orders and purchases and link them to a partner, that can be selected from the partnersystem. The link back from partner to sale and purchase is implemented as roles in the partner system.

Click the links and try.

peter
Dortmund, Germany